# Label editing (EditLabel) in CView class ignores mouse clicks

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I have an application that uses a CView class with a CListCtrl as its main control.  When I use the EditLabel function, its 'works' in that the label editing is started, the existing characters are highlighted, and I can use the keyboard arrow keys to move around and change the text.  But I can't get the mouse to be recognized.  So if the end-user wants to click somewhere in the existing text and modify it, the click is not recognized.  Only the arrow keys, home, end, etc can be used to navigate the Editing cell.

This application also uses several dialogs with CListCtrl, and an in-place edit allows use of the mouse just fine.

So, there seems to be something in either the application or the framework that is capturing the mouse click in the CEdit control.

This application has a lot of event handlers, but the OnClick event is not called when in Edit mode. The PretranslateMessage handler is called, but the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message is not processed.  I can set a trap for it, but don't know where to send the message anyway.

Is there something that I am missing on where the mouse click events go ?

Comment: I would be very surprised if MFC was to blame here. More likely IMO is that another app (or your own) is in fact causing the problem.

Comment: Use Spy++ to determine why the mouse click is not accepted.

Comment: I did use Spy++, and can see the mouse click event, but don't see any difference to the other uses of this same control (just not in a CView). I'll try to learn more about Spy++ to see if I can see where the message is 'going'.  I don't know how to trace that in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem with edit controls embedded on a CFormView-derived class.

Although enabled, and lit up accordingly, the controls would behave as though they were disabled, or enabled but covered with a "force field" that would prevent its use. It could not be selected using the mouse. It did not appear to be a state consistent with the MFC literature.

I mostly resolved the issue by subclassing the MFC CEdit control and adding the following message map entry - ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN() - and its handler:

```
void CMyEdit::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    auto bEnabled = IsWindowEnabled();
    BOOL bReadOnly = GetStyle() & ES_READONLY;
    //ShowCursor(TRUE);
    //ShowCaret();// Does nothing

    // New logic to circumvent "force field" that prevents editing the control's contents
    // Identify the position that the mouse was clicked on
    auto ptMousePos = (CPoint)GetMessagePos();
    ScreenToClient(&ptMousePos);
    auto nChar = CharFromPos(ptMousePos);

    CEdit::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
    if (bEnabled)
    {
        auto pWnd = SetFocus();// Grab the focus
        TRACE(_T("Got focus \n"));

        // Explicitly select the character
        int nStartChar, nEndChar;// troubleshooting
        GetSel(nStartChar, nEndChar);// troubleshooting
        SetSel(nChar, nChar);// Automatically handles nChar overflow
    }
}
```

The handler does most of what we need for functionality, with minor differences. For example, you cannot drag-select text in the edit control.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But I don't know how to get a notification for my CEdit which is created on the fly by the CListCtrl when I initiate an ::EditLabel on it.  I verified that in the ::OnBeginLabelEdit that I can change the selection and stuff, but can't get it to recognize mouse clicks.  I am assuming your CEdit label was a control on your form?

Comment: That's correct. Our CEdit control was on our CFormView-derived class. You mentioned earlier that you were able to trap the mouse click message in PreTranslateMsg. When you do this, if you can get to the edit control, you may be able to troubleshoot and manipulate it into behaving the way you want. With the CListCtrl in the way, though, it'll be a tall order.